# Списки. Не знаю как обратиться к конкретному значению

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Есть список, мне нужно обратиться к строке 2 [5,12], это понятно как сделать. Но я не понимаю как вызвать из строки 5,12 отдельно число 5 или 12. Ответа не нашел, может быть неправильно задаю вопрос

```
a=[[1,3],[5,12],[6,9],[5,4],[3,3],[1,5]]
```

Comment: `a[1][0] # -> 5`

Comment: Примите ответ, если он вам помог(галочка около ответа).

Answer (score 0):

Вот так:

```
a[1][1] #or first a[1][0]
```